# Inability to change monitor's display

Tags: linux, software-updates

It seems that my monitor's display can't be changed from 1024 x 728. I read that this may be due to a new update. I use Linux Mint 20.2 Uma. Should I try updating my GPU drivers? Should I move to an older version? Is there anything else that may be the problem? I have an Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller.

Comment: No info about your monitor... How the heck are we supposed to help you? Anyway, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` will tell you what it believes the monitor is capable of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that due to an update, Linux Mint couldn't configure the monitor by itself. First, I had to use `xrandr --listmonitors` to find out what my outputs are. Then, after I figured that out, I used a combination of three commands that I added in my .profile file. These are:

```bsh
xrandr --newmode 1930x1080_60.00 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync -Vsync
xrandr --addmode <output_name> 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output <output_name> --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

(where <output_name> is the one from `xrandr --listmonitors`). After that, the resolution was fixed at FHD, only after I login. The login screen is still set at 1024x728. I haven't found a solution for that. If anyone knows, feel free to tell us.